# Examples of noncommutative ring where Fermats Last Theorem fails for n=4

Tags: number-theory

Does anyone have an example where this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ring of $2\times 2$ real matrices, for instance. Where we have
$$
X^4+X^4=(\sqrt[4]2 X)^4
$$
for any element $X$.